# Angular 6 - Chrome in IOS - Router problem

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome, google-cast, angular-router

I'm working on an Angular 6 web site and I face a weird problem only on Chrome in IOS (iPad, iPhone).

Each page renders correctly when going directly to each link. But when I click on any of the links inside any page, it generates a NavigationError like these one:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 ('other') to Node.contains must be an instance of Node
TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.insertBefore must be an instance of Node
```

It's really difficult to debug Chrome inside IOS so it's hard to get more information.

My web site is working well on any other browsers and OS, Firefox(windows, linux), Chrome (windows and linux), Safari (ios, osx, windows).

Anyone got an idea where to start looking?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is happening only on Google Chrome iOS when this code is present:

```
let script = window['document'].createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1');
window['document'].body.appendChild(script);
window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function (isAvailable) { /*Do chromecast initialization*/}
```

So I added this condition:

```
if(!navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS'))
```

Problem resolved.

I really don't know why cast framework is breaking angular routing.